# Spring boot - Python integration

Tags: python, spring

Hi All I have been trying to get Spring boot to python integration , which I did successfully using two different method but both required downloading the python module, which initally i thought ok everything is in Python lib folder , as my python files are mostly using to fetcg data via Rest call ( Rest client )  i needed Python Requests Module to be add.  Here where all problems started Request module have many imports and then each import have more imports and its never ending and still some module i couldnt find and there are still many errors and it never execute and complains for imports.

- Using intellij and i did got python plugins and SDK set , why I need to download modules . I did python project in Pycharm and there i dont need to download modules in the projects just need to set interpreter , is any way i can just set and using interpreter it using module from LIB folder like java do using JDK.
- I am Java developer and never worked in python and i have no issue in python code , I have created whole project in pycharm .
- Hello world simple python file from spring boot working only problem starts when add request module for Rest client.

Please help i am only developer at my work :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Hi all please share your views even if thats not a answer , i am quite stuck here and a discussion would be helpful too